# Print ASA without enclosure

Tags: filament, enclosure, asa

Is it possible or recommended to print with ASA filament with printer that has no enclosure? I Know that ASA is better than ABS, but is it that better that enclosure is not needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MatterHackers](https://www.matterhackers.com/articles/how-to-succeed-when-3d-printing-with-asa-filament), [Simplify3D](https://www.simplify3d.com/support/materials-guide/asa/), and [3D Insider](https://www.simplify3d.com/support/materials-guide/asa/) an enclosure is not necessary but highly recommended as ASA, like ABS, is susceptible to drafts and can warp. A heated bed is necessary (somewhere between 90-110 °C), and little-to-no cooling fan used. The enclosure helps ensure adhesion and a consistent temperature. ASA also has fumes and an enclosure can help contain unwanted smells.

MattHackers has a video (Step 4 in the link) on making an enclosure with some kind of plastic sheeting or trash bag (I didn't watch it). There are videos on YouTube on using cheap Ikea side tables and acrylic sheets to make an enclosure if you want a more permanent solution.

Comment: "can help contain unwanted smells". I heard that ABS(and guess ASA) releases toxic vapors/smell/something. Is it true? I'm really sad that ASA needs enclosure. Does exist filament that has similar mechanical properties as ABS/ASA but it doesn't require enclosure?

Comment: @SilvioCro You may be able to get away without an enclosure, just make sure that it's a well ventilated area. PETG seems to have a similar hardiness that ABS has but prints similar to PLA (though at higher temperatures). I don't have experience with anything outside of PLA so I can't really comment. Although, my understanding is that the main plus to ASA is that it handles outdoors a lot better than ABS.

Comment: @SilvioCro Woops, missed the question on toxicity in your comment. ABS/ASA does release toxic vapours, but as long as there is adequate ventilation then there shouldn't be any problem. Typically it's an issue of comfort and not safety (but this assumes that the user is responsible and ensuring ventilation).

Comment: a big cardboard box might be enough; cheap, low effort, fairly effective.